# Chamar procedure sql server via JDBC que retorna cursor

Tags: java, oracle, algoritmo, sql-server-2012

Não estou conseguindo chamar uma Procedure SQL Server em java que retorna um cursor.

Isso é possível, alguém tem algum exemplo ?

Pelo Oracle consigui, através do exemplo: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-cursor-example/. Mas preciso no SQl Server.

Comment: Pode colocar o seu trecho de código e o erro retornado?

Comment: Na verdade eu não encontrei nenhum exemplo em sql server, sabe de algum ?

Comment: Acho que é basicamente trocar o DB_DRIVER do exemplo para `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver`. Já viu esse exemplo aqui [iMasters - Conectando o Java ao SQL Server](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/2048/sql_server/conectando_o_java_ao_sql_server/) ?

Comment: Eu consegui chamar a procedure passando os parametro o problema é quando utilizo um cursor no output de Procedure Store, por no oracle em declaro: callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR); e no sql server não sei fazer.